# Why is my database using Partitioning? ( I know it's not )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Running this query:

```
select * from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

Shows me that I'm using Partitioning:

```
| feature_name | feature_id |
|--------------|------------|
| Partitioning | 200        |
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm not using partitioning, since this database is only mine, and it's for consulting. There are 3 tables that I created using simple "create table" statements. There's no index on tables too. So, why is SQL Server saying that this database is using Partitioning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-persisted-sku-features-transact-sql), this will return a value if the database has any of the following:

- Partitioned tables
- Partitioned indexes
- Partition schemes
- Partition functions

So check for and remove any partition schemes or functions, even if they aren't in use. You can do this in the SSMS UI (Database > Storage > Partition Schemes/Functions), or by querying the following system views:

- `sys.partition_schemes`
- `sys.partition_functions`

Comment: Wow I could find an object for each select. But why is it there? I didn't created it.

Comment: @RacerSQL Pretty hard for us to tell you that. SQL Server didn't do it.

Comment: @RacerSQL If you're positive you didn't do it and that nobody else did either, perhaps someone added them to the `model` database (which is copied when you create a new blank database)?

Comment: No No, it was the first thing I did ( to look at the model database ). No one has access here. I use it only to store some procedures. Strange, but it helped me. i will look for answers about this. thanks